# PostgreSQL Backups with Docker(cookiecutter)

Tags: django, windows, docker

Try to backup postgres data using cookiecutter on windows, follwed [instructions](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker-postgres-backups.html) here

```
PS C:\Users\Super\Desktop\mysite\mysite> docker-compose -f local.yml exec postgres backups
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pg_dump` to backup the data, btw, pg_dump is available in [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/), check it out